# vue how set default props for nested object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

my props is like this

```
house = {
  kitchen:{
    sink: ''
  }
}
```

I tried something like this, didnt work.

```
props: {
    house: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {
            kitchen : {
                sink: ''
            }
        }
    }
},
```

How to set default props for such object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following solution should work :

```
  props: {
   house: {
       type: Object,
        default: () => ({
          kitchen: {
             sink:''
            }
       })
  },
 }
```

check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/3m5k5420q)

if the above solution doesn't work, you could use a normalized computed property :

```
     props: {
         house: { type: Object }
       },
    computed: {
           normalizedHouse() {
              return {
                      kitchen:{
                         sink: ''
                        }
                     }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Is it possible to set an object with 2 values:

`kitchen: {
 sink: 'yes',
 windows: 3
}`

And when using the `<component :kitchen={sink: 'no'}/>` and then the last default option windows get 3 as default? i don't seem to be able to do this default behavior like that with nested objects and default values

Comment: Yes, of course !

Comment: I've posted my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72992210/vue3-composition-api-with-typescript-default-values-for-nested-objects-not-worki

Hope you can see what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 16):

From the docs:

> Object or array defaults must be returned from a factory function

So the problem is that you are not returning the default object.So you can either do:

```
props: {
    house: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => ({ // <= note the parenthesis
            kitchen : {
                sink: ''
            }
        }) // <= here also
    }
},
```

Or

```
props: {
    house: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {
           return  {
              kitchen : { // <= note the return
                sink: ''
              }
           } 
        }
    }
},
```