# Vue3 Composition API with Typescript Default Values for nested objects not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, default, vue-composition-api

I want to be able to set default values for nested datasets in Vue, basically, if a key does not have a value in the dataset that is being parsed to the component, I would like that value to be filled in automatically. This kinda works looking into this example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53143723/vue-how-set-default-props-for-nested-object/53143977?noredirect=1#comment128919189_53143977). However, my sample which is nested with several keys in the main object seems not to work. Why is that? what am I doing wrong?

**Test Component**

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import {defineProps, PropType} from 'vue';

export type KitchenType = {
    windows: number;
};

export type DefaultTestType = {
    kitchen?: KitchenType;
    rooms?: number;
};

const props = defineProps({
    dataset: {
        type: Object as PropType<DefaultTestType>,
        default: () => ({
            kitchen: {
                windows: 5,
            },
            rooms: 3,
        })
    },
});

console.log('IAM DATASET: ', props.dataset);
</script>
```

Calling the Component

```
<DefaultTest :dataset="{
    rooms: 5,
}" />
```

Console.log result

```
{ rooms: 5 }
```

Console.log expected result

```
{ kitchen: { windows: 5, }, rooms: 5 }
```

I'm using Laravel 9 with Vite, Inertia and Vue3 and have enabled the `reactivityTransform: true` in the `vite.config` file as told [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/reactivity-transform.html#explicit-opt-in) through [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#props-default-values)

If I don't pass any dataset object, I am getting all the default values

Answer (score 5):

Have you ever tried [withDefaults](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#defineprops-defineemits) macro to define props with the default value

```
export interface Props {
  msg?: string
  labels?: string[]
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  msg: 'hello',
  labels: () => ['one', 'two']
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to do such a thing with the use of *default*. Although you can create a default object then with the use of the **Object.assign()** method create a new object with default values, which will be overwritten by the prop you will receive.

```js
const deafult = { kitchen: { windows: 5, }, rooms: 5 };

const recive = {rooms: 3}; //a prop

const mergedValues = Object.assign(deafult, recive);

console.log(mergedValues)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to use `withDefaults` with a default object:

```
interface CustomStyles {
  padding: string
  margin: string
}
interface Props {
  message: string
  styles: CustomStyles
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  message: "test",
  customStyles: () => ({ 
    padding: "5px",
    margin: "4px"
  }) // notice the round brackets around the object
})
```